# Mongo query to find where no matching element after a different matching element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection (that I don't control) with documents like the following that are used as a log of jobs per job definition:

```
{
    "definition": ...,
    "jobs": [ // sequential
        {
            "time": ...,
            "result": "success"
        },
        {
            "time": ... (after previous),
            "result": "failure"
        }
        {
            "time": ...,
            "result": "running"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find each job definition where the most recent **completed** job run is a failure where "failure" and "success" are the only two "completed" result types, but there may be any number of other results unknown to me.

So far I have come up with this to find all the jobs with failures:

```
db.collection.find({jobs: {$elemMatch: {result: "failure"}}})
```

I can certainly get the list of failure and programmatically search filter those to match my specific requirements if this can't be done with pure mongo.

**Edit:**

I'm constrained to using mongo 2.6. I can ignore any non-failure and non-success results, but there could be any number of them before, after, and in-between successful and failure results.

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? did you think that the current title describe well your problem?

Comment: @user3100115 I don't think that my title describes it particularly well, but yours was a bit misleading since I'm not looking for the last element necessarily. See edit comments.

Comment: If you are not looking for the last, what do you mean by *the most recent completed job run is a failure*?

Comment: I mean that it's possible that an "incomplete" job will be the last element. I want the last "complete" job, but it may not be the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is beyond a basic `find()` query. You need to use the aggregation framework.

The most efficient way to do this is in MongoDB 3.2 or newer because we have the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which can be used in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to get the last element in the array using index `-1`, but here you should use the `$arrayElemAt` because it returns the element while `$slice` returns one element array. Also, you need to use the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator to access the "result" field in the sub-document  using [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

The first stage in your pipeline must be [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage. This reduces both the amount of data sent over the wire and the time and memory used down in the pipeline.

The last stage in the pipeline is also `$match` stage where you select only those documents that match your criteria.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "jobs.result": "failure" } }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "definition": 1,
        "result": { 
            "$let": { 
                "vars": { "job": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$jobs", -1 ] } },
                "in": "$$job.result" 
            } 
        } 
    }}, 
    { "$match": { "result": "failure" } } 
])
```

---

From MongoDB 3.0 backwards you need a different approach which is less efficient as it implies that you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the "jobs" array after matching and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by `_id`, use the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator operator to get the last element in the array. Of course the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator in the group stage is used to retain the "definition" field value.

After grouping your documents, You need to use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline stage which returns all documents where the last "job" matches your criteria using a logical condition to `$$KEEP` the document when the condition is `true` or `$$PRUNE` it where it's `false`.

The final stage is the `$project` where you specify the fields that you want to include in your result. This also reduces both the amount of data sent over the wire and the time and memory used to decode documents on the client-side.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "jobs.result": "failure" } }, 
    { "$unwind": "$jobs" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "job": { "$last": "$jobs" }, 
        "definition": { "$first": "$definition" } 
    }}, 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ "$job.result", "failure" ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }}, 
    // optional stage
    { "$project": { 
        "definition": 1, 
        "result": "$job.result" 
    }} 
])
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm constrained to using mongo 2.6

Comment: @RobertHickman the second query will work on 2.6. Did you even try it?

Comment: no but I have since and I get `"errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$redact'"`

Comment: [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) is new in version 2.6, so if you're getting that error message it's means you are on 2.4 or 2.2.

Comment: `mongos> version()`
`2.6.4`

Comment: @RobertHickman You probably doing something wrong that I can't see from here.

Comment: When I have more time in a couple of hours I will try messing with your code to see if I can figure out why it isn't working for me. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: So this must show my ignorance with `aggregate()`, but when I run the code, it doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't show any normal output either, just another `>` prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113182/discussion-between-user3100115-and-robert-hickman).

Answer (score 0):

you could use aggregation framework for that

```
  db.robert.aggregate([     
         {
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                def : 1,
                jobs : { //filter only fields by OK/NOK
                    $filter : {
                        input : "$jobs",
                        as : "item",
                        cond : {
                            $or : [{
                                    $eq :
                                    [{
                                            $cmp : ["$$item.staus", "success"]
                                        }, 0]
                                }, {
                                    $eq : [{
                                            $cmp : ["$$item.staus", "failure"]
                                        }, 0]
                                }
                            ]

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                def : 1,
                jobs : {
                    $slice : ["$jobs", 2]//take first two entries of array
                    // this could be also last two use -2
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                jobs : {
                    $size : 2 //eliminate nulls and only one entry in the array
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : { // this is a kind of creating parameters for $match
                _id : 1,
                def : 1,
                firstShouldBeFalied : {
                    $slice : ["$jobs", 1]
                },
                secondShouldBeSuccess : {
                    $slice : ["$jobs", 1, 1]
                },
            }
        }, {
            $match : {

                $and : [{
                        "firstShouldBeFalied.staus" : "failure"
                    }, {
                        "secondShouldBeSuccess.staus" : "success"
                    },
                ]

            }
        },

    ])
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: I hadn't heard of the aggregation framework until today. It sounds interesting. Would you mind explaining the query you wrote? At first glance it seems limited to taking elements in the array at a particular index. If that's true, it won't work for me. In my case, I could have a failure, any number of non-complete statuses, and then a successful status. So I have no way of knowing which indices to check.

Comment: @RobertHickman ok - so that means that we can eliminate other statuses from array and focus only OK/NOK?, will edit answer to give you an overview - but more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: Yeah we can totally ignore any other statuses besides the success and failure statuses. I think I see how that would help to change your query and get the result I need.

Comment: @RobertHickman - please see edit with query which `$filter` input fields and then process them

Comment: Perhaps this is because I didn't specify I need code compliant with mongo 2.6, but I get this error: `"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$filter'"`

Comment: @roberthickman that's making a difference :) will try later to think about that